# How to pass variables from Puppet module manifest to module provider?

Tags: ruby, variables, module, puppet

I am trying to use a custom Puppet provider called 'ldapdn' from: https://github.com/gtmtechltd/puppet_ldapdn/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider/ldapdn/ldapdn.rb

The problem is that this assumes SASL auth against LDAP, while I need to specify a '-w password' argument in the command line to authorize with my LDAP servers. The password is stored in Puppet modules variable (coming from Hiera) and the question is if there's a way to pass that variable to this provider, so it could actually connect to the LDAP server?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new parameter to the type :

```
newparam(:password) do
  desc "Specify the value of the password to connect to ldap"
end
```

then access the value in the provider with `resource[:password]`

in the manifest you'll need to specify the password when declaring the resource

```
ldapdn{'something':
  password => $my_ldap_password
  other_params => ...
  etc
}
```